# Why am i getting error

Tags: python, pygame

The error:

```
Error   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/enrique/Dropbox/Public/pygametut3.py", line 41, in <module>
    pix = MovingPixel(width/2, height/2)
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

The Code:

```
#Creat a moving pixel
pix = MovingPixel(width/2, height/2)

while running:
    pix.move()

    if pix.x <= 0 or pix.x >= width or pix.y <= 0 or pix.y >= height:
        print "Crash"
        running = False
```

Comment: If the answer to your question is "read the error message", then it is a non-question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `MovingPixel` needs to be instantiated with no arguments:

```
pix = MovingPixel()
```

Answer (score 0):

You created the MovingPixel object passing two arguments to the constructor, it requires no arguments. Did you forget to import the right module?

If you are referring to something like this: http://lorenzod8n.wordpress.com/tag/python/ you should know that MovingPixel is not a built-in class, and you have to download the module/source if you want to use it.

Comment: that happens to be the exact tutorial im doing...